# How to launch a onStopTrackingTouch event by passing a value to SeekBar.progress?

Tags: android

The `verticalSeekBar` is a SeekBar control of Android. I hope to launch `onStopTrackingTouch` event when I pass a value to `verticalSeekBar.progress`, how can I do it?

BTW, the `onProgressChanged` event is launched automatically when I pass a value to `verticalSeekBar.progress`.

**Code A**

```
 verticalSeekBar.progress=3

 verticalSeekBar?.setOnVerticalSeekBarChangeListener(
        object : MyVerticalSeekBar.OnVerticalSeekBarChangeListener {

            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: MyVerticalSeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                  toast("Change")
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: MyVerticalSeekBar) {

            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: MyVerticalSeekBar) {
                toast("Stop")                    
                zoomX(seekBar.progress.toFloat())
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The verticalSeekBar is a SeekBar control of Android Studio, I hope to
>   launch onStopTrackingTouch event when I pass a value to
>   verticalSeekBar.progress, how can I do?

Add this funtion to `MyVerticalSeekBar` class.

```
fun setSeekBarProgress(progress: Int) {
    mChangeListener?.onStopTrackingTouch(this)
    super.progress = progress
}
```

Using `setSeekBarProgress()` method instead of `progress` whenever you want to change progress value.

```
// verticalSeekBar.progress = 10 // Do not use this
verticalSeekBar.setSeekBarProgress(10) // Use this instead
```

> BTW, the onProgressChanged event is launched automatically when I pass
>   a value to verticalSeekBar.progress.

I think this is desired behavior, because `onProgressChanged()` will be called when `progress` state of MyVerticalSeekBar changed.

If you still want to prevent this method from launched automatically (based on your requirements), then you can apply these codes to `MyVerticalSeekBar` class.

**Step 1:** Add this variable

```
private var invokeOnProgressChanged: Boolean = true
```

**Step 2:** Modify `setOnVerticalSeekBarChangeListener` method, see comment line with *[IMPORTANT]* note.

```
fun setOnVerticalSeekBarChangeListener(listener: OnVerticalSeekBarChangeListener?) {
    mChangeListener = listener
    // We will use the progress listener as defined in VerticalSeekBar.
    if (listener == null) {
        super.setOnProgressChangeListener(null)
    } else {
        super.setOnProgressChangeListener { newProgress ->
            // [IMPORTANT] - Add these lines of code
            if (!invokeOnProgressChanged) {
                invokeOnProgressChanged = true
                return@setOnProgressChangeListener
            }

            listener.onProgressChanged(this, newProgress, true)
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Modify `setSeekBarProgress()` method

```
fun setSeekBarProgress(progress: Int, invokeOnProgressChanged: Boolean = true) {
    mChangeListener?.onStopTrackingTouch(this)
    this.invokeOnProgressChanged = invokeOnProgressChanged
    super.progress = progress
}
```

Using in your code.

1.If you want to launch `onStopTrackingTouch` event when changing progress value

```
verticalSeekBar.setSeekBarProgress(10)
```

2.If you want to launch `onStopTrackingTouch` event when changing progress value **AND** prevent `onProgressChanged()` from invoking.

```
verticalSeekBar.setSeekBarProgress(10, invokeOnProgressChanged = false)
```